# Slow load time with UITextView as compared to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I am working on a project that creates a form dynamically based on an XML file. Everything works fine, except that if a form has too many textViews, it loads very slowly. Analyzing the app performance through xcode Time profiler, I came to know that whenever a textView is initailized it consumes a lot of CPU.

To make this easier to understand, I created a sample project that recreates this issue. The sample project just adds about 1000 UITextViews when a `ViewController` is loaded. I checked the performance of this code using Xcode Profiler. I was able to figure out that if UITextView is replaced by UITextField, the performance increases dramatically. The demo project would show a slight improvement since the view is limited with just textviews or textfields. But in my actual app, I see an improvement of 4 seconds minimum when I try to load a heavy XML.

**Sample Project:** https://github.com/amrit42087/TextView_Performance

**Here is the screenshot of the Xcode Profiler with UITextView:**

[image]

**Here is the screenshot of the Xcode Profiler with UITextField:**

[image]

UITextField reduces the load time to 960 ms from 1.49 seconds which is in case of UITextView. My actual project notices quite a lot of improvement since that is a heavy application.

**Question:** If anyone could suggest a solution to improve the performance while using a UITextView, that would be greatly appreciated. Using UITextField is not an option since I need multiline text.

Comment: Show relevant code in your question. FYI - I have a screen with 8 UITextView instances and that view controller loads instantly. It's certainly not taking .68 seconds per text view to initialize.

Comment: Lots of ways to do something incorrectly and cause problems. If I try to load 1000 4K images, it will take a long time (and problem cause a memory crash). The simple answer is: *"I shouldn't do that."* -- If you are seeing a **4 seconds minimum** difference, then: *"You shouldn't do that."* Evaluate what it is that you're doing and ***why*** you're taking the wrong approach.

Comment: @HangarRash I have attached a demo project that recreates this issue. And the time profiler shows isn't per UITextView. It's the time takes to load 1000 UITextViews.

Comment: @DonMag I donot have an option to avoid creating multiple textviews. I have explained the scenario as a comment to below answer.

Comment: @AmritSidhu - there are big differences between *what I **want** to do* -- *what I **CAN** do* -- *what I **shouldn't** do* -- *what I **CANNOT** do* . Your comment of "an xml might have 20 pages in a form and each page might be having 100 textview to enter data" could be interpreted as **shouldn't** do. I'd recommend re-thinking your approach. Or, since you also say *"also makes use of javascript"* you **could** format it as html and use a `WKWebView`

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't work for our solution. It's a well established product that can not be asked to change the complete approach how a UI is rendered but yes minor tweaks are most welcome.

Comment: @AmritSidhu - well, if you cannot change the approach, you're kind of out-of-luck. Another suggestion would be to use labels, and only display a `UITextVIew` when editing... but that would be changing "the complete approach." So...  it sounds like you need to add some sort of animated progress view to let the user know your code is formatting the UI.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the suggestion again. The form that loads in 15 seconds in iOS only takes about a second in android. This is what is not letting us change the approach. Since, android is working fine, we cannot afford to remake both ios and android just because of an issue in one platform. I can still try the next suggestion for replacing it with labels.

Comment: @AmritSidhu - ***15 seconds in iOS** only takes about a second in android*??? Gotta wonder what else you are doing that is taking up so much time. Maybe use a table view and split your "20 pages" into 20 rows... or, "20 pages" into 20 sections and split "page" elements into rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have no idea what else you might be doing...

One thing to try is to use a `UIView` subclass that contains a label and a text view. Only show the text view after tapping on the label.

Try replacing your `SecondViewController` with this:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    var myData: [String] = []
    
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0),

        ])

        spinner.style = .large
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        spinner.startAnimating()
        
        myData = (1...1000).compactMap({ "Element \($0)" })

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: {
            self.addTheViews()
        })
    }

    func addTheViews() {
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        let n: Int = 1000
        for i in 0..<n {
            addTextView(i)
        }
        
        let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
        print("Took \(diff) seconds")
        
        spinner.stopAnimating()
    }
    
    private func addTextView(_ idx: Int) {
        let textView = MyTextView()
        textView.myID = idx
        textView.text = myData[idx]
        textView.backgroundColor = .white
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textView)
    }
    
}
```

and an example `MyTextView` class:

```
class MyTextView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    public var myID: Int = 0
    
    public var text: String = "" {
        didSet { label.text = text }
    }
    
    public var textChanged: ((Int, String) -> ())?
    
    private let label = UILabel()
    private var textView: UITextView!
    private var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
    }
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if textView == nil {
            textView = UITextView()
            if let f = label.font {
                textView.font = f
            }
        }
        textView.text = self.text
        textView.frame = self.bounds
        textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        addSubview(textView)
        
        textView.delegate = self
        
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textChanged?(myID, textView.text ?? "")
    }
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.removeFromSuperview()
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
}
```

This is, of course, just a "starting point" but my be helpful.

Comment: DonMag, Thank you taking time to help me out. This seems to be helpful. I checked the performance using Profiler. The performance is drastically reduced if I replace the UILabel in your code with just UItextView. This makes clear that UITextView does take little longer as compared to other UI elements to be rendered.

Your suggested code is definitely a starting point for me and would help me improve the performance. I am gonna accept this answer. But I would also like to give some credit to @Evgeny Karkan, whose clarifications did make sense to me why a UITextView would render slowly.

Comment: Hey @DonMag, I just replaced my UITextView with your MyTextView. I was amazed to see the performance improved by 50%. A form that took 8 seconds to render was loaded in just 3.69 seconds after the update. Thank you for the support!

Comment: @AmritSidhu - glad it helped... I suspect (based on your other comments) there are a number of things you're doing that could be done much quicker.